# Loop through each cell in a given range and change the value depending on value in a column in the same row

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code to change the value in the range H2:K2 as an example of the conditions. But I need it to loop through all of the coloured cells.

The range needs to be set by selecting all of the coloured cells and check it against the values in  column "Product"

However the range of coloured cells won't be the same each time the Macro is run, plus the Value (Column P) to be checked won't always be in Column P.

If the value doesn't match any of the conditions in the If statement, then no change is to made to the cell

[image: Spreadsheet]

Any help would be much appreciated

```
Sub Turn_Live_Digital()

If Range("p2").Value = "ADSHEL LIVE" Or _
   Range("p2").Value = "ASDA LIVE" Or _
   Range("p2").Value = "CC DIGITAL MALLS" Or _
   Range("p2").Value = "CCB DIGITAL" Or _
   Range("p2").Value = "MALLS XL" Or _
   Range("p2").Value = "SAINSBURYS LIVE" Or _
   Range("p2").Value = "SOCIALITE" Or _
   Range("p2").Value = "STATION LIVE" Or _
   Range("p2").Value = "STORM DIGITAL" _
Then
    Range("h2:k2").Value = "Digital"
End If
End Sub
```

I wouldn't know where to start

Comment: Is the code located in the same workbook as the worksheet? What is the tab name of the worksheet? What does *"However the range of coloured cells won't be the same each time the Macro is run, plus the Value (Column P) to be checked won't always be in Column P."* mean i.e. how should we identify the correct columns? Or does it just mean that there will be more or fewer rows?

Comment: The code will be be added to an existing Macro in my PersonalXLS file.

Comment: With the change in the post and the last comment, I am concluding that I have to identify the column by the header (`Product`) and that the code should work for the active sheet, I will take care of that the code doesn't accidentally run on your `PERSONAL.xlsb`. The only information I still need is about the colored cells. Will they always be in columns `H:K`?

Comment: The code will be be added to an existing Macro in my PersonalXLS file, so it can be run on any spreadsheet. if you look at the coloured cell column titles they are dates. on another spreadsheet there might be 7 columns of dates and 40 rows of coloured cells. I need it to run on any tab (but if it helps you - Name it "Avails"  .Please Identify the column titled "Product" for the conditions in the IF statement. Basically yes there will be more or fewer coloured rows and columns. And the product column might be in a different column on another spreadsheet. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: The coloured columns might be any number of columns and rows

Comment: Identifying by color is always a bad idea. I will identify them by the numbers in their titles. Please tell me that they are the only ones beginning with a digit so I can just check each first character.

Comment: Yes they are the only columns beginning with a digit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Process Columns Identified By Headers

```vb
Sub TurnLiveDigital()
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Turn Live Digital"
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const PRODUCT_HEADER As String = "Product"
    Const PRODUCTS_LIST As String = "" _
        & "ADSHEL LIVE,ASDA LIVE,CC DIGITAL MALLS,CCB DIGITAL,MALLS XL" _
        & "SAINSBURYS LIVE,SOCIALITE,STATION LIVE,STORM DIGITAL"
    Const PRODUCTS_DEL As String = ","
    Const DATE_CRITERION As String = "Digital"
    
    ' Allow to run on any worksheet that is not in 'PERSONAL.xlsb'.
    
    If Not IsActiveWorksheet Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Reference the active sheet.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    ' Reference the ranges.
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.UsedRange
    Dim hrg As Range: Set hrg = rg.Rows(1)
    
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = rg.Rows.Count - 1
    
    If drCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No data found.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = rg.Resize(drCount).Offset(1)
    
    ' Identify the Product column.
    
    Dim pcIndex: pcIndex = Application.Match(PRODUCT_HEADER, hrg, 0)
    
    If IsError(pcIndex) Then
        MsgBox "Product column not found.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim prg As Range: Set prg = drg.Columns(pcIndex)
    
    ' Identify the Date columns by leading digit.
    
    Dim durg As Range, dCell As Range
    
    For Each dCell In hrg.Cells
        If CStr(dCell.Value) Like "#*" Then ' begins with a digit
            If durg Is Nothing Then
                Set durg = dCell
            Else
                Set durg = Union(durg, dCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next dCell
    
    If durg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No Date column found.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    ' Write the products from the list to an array.
    
    Dim Products() As String: Products = Split(PRODUCTS_LIST, PRODUCTS_DEL)
        
    ' Write the products from the array to a dictionary.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 0 To UBound(Products)
        dict(Products(n)) = Empty
    Next n
    
    Erase Products
    
    ' Identify the matching cells in the Product column.
    
    Dim purg As Range, pCell As Range
    
    For Each pCell In prg.Cells
        If dict.Exists(CStr(pCell.Value)) Then
            If purg Is Nothing Then
                Set purg = pCell
            Else
                Set purg = Union(purg, pCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next pCell
    
    If purg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No matches found.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set dict = Nothing
    
    ' Write the criterion.
    
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = Intersect(purg.EntireRow, durg.EntireColumn)
    crg.Value = DATE_CRITERION
 
    ' Inform.
 
    MsgBox "Turned Live Digital.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

End Sub


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns a boolean indicating whether the active sheet
'               is a worksheet not located in 'PERSONAL.xlsb'.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function IsActiveWorksheet() As Boolean
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Is Not Active Worksheet"
    If ThisWorkbook Is ActiveWorkbook Then
        MsgBox "Can't run on ""PERSONAL.xlsb"". " _
            & "Select the correct worksheet.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Function
    End If
    If ActiveSheet Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No visible workbooks open.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Function
    End If
    If Not TypeOf ActiveSheet Is Worksheet Then
        MsgBox "The active sheet is not a worksheet.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Function
    End If
    IsActiveWorksheet = True
End Function
```

Comment: It works! thank you very much - I had to take out the line "If Not IsActiveWorksheet Then Exit Sub"  It made the code skip to the end, even though I was on the active worksheet. It works perfectly without it :)

Comment: Hi, I've been doing some testing and it doesn't work if the Product is either MALLS XL or SAINSBURYS LIVE - Any idea why?

Comment: All fine now, I must have removed a comma from the Product list some how.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would just use match() and if() without code at all, like so:

```
IF(IFERROR(MATCH(C3,A4:A12,0),0)>0,"Digital","")
```

If the string in C3 does not exist then the iferror converts to 0, if the result is greater than 0 then the if() puts "Digital".
The list structure means adding or editing is easier that dealing with changes in code - imho.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this won't solve my problem, as there will be values in column P that are not a digital product, so I don't want the corresponding value in those cells changed. They need to remain as either "booked" or "Swappable" I only need it to change if it matches any of the Values in my IF statement. There will be Values that don't match.

Comment: Then add an if() to deal with your extra conditions, if this is one of those questions that will run like an old sock I won't consider any edits.